# Flickr API and JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flickr

For an assignment we need to use Flickr API to get a string of photos to appear when a certain category is clicked. I have my categories on the left side of a flexbox container but I'm not sure how to get the text 'tennis' when clicked to show the Flickr API of everything with the tag tennis.

Also with the Flickr API, the photos don't have their titles under them which is what I needed as well. The images also show up in a column no matter how much I edit them. Could anyone help me with this?

I'm a beginner to coding so I would love some clarification on how these things are done.

Here is the code:

```js
$("#tennis").click(function() {

  //api search for tennis
  let API_KEY = MY API KEY ";
  let tennisStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&tags=tennis&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&" + API_KEY;
  let photos = [];
  let nrequest;
  let nreceived;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(tennisStr);
    $.get(tennisStr, function(data) {
      fetchPhoto(data);
    });
  });

  function fetchPhoto(data) {
    nrequest = data.photos.photo.length;
    nreceived = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
      let photoObj = {
        id: data.photos.photo[i].id,
        title: data.photos.photo[0].title
      }
      photos.push(photoObj);
      getSizes(photoObj);
    }

    function getSizes(photoObj) {
      let getSizesStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&" + API_KEY + "&photo_id=" + photoObj.id;
      $.get(getSizesStr, function(data) {
        nreceived++;
        photoObj.file = data.sizes.size[5].source;
        photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length - 1].source;
        if (nreceived == nrequest) {
          display(photos);
        }
      });
    }

    function display(photos) {
      let htmlStr = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
        htmlStr += `<figure><a href=${photos[i].file}'><img src = "${photos[i].file}" height = "200" width = "200"></a><figcaption>photos</figcaption></figure>`;
      }
      $("#flickrphoto").html(htmlStr);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navigation {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

#flickrphoto {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

#recenthistory {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  <title>Sports Album</title>
  <header>
    <h1>Sports Album</h1>
  </header>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="navigation">
      <h2>Categories</h2><br>
      <div id="nav">
        <div id="tennis">
          <p>Tennis</p>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div id="football">
          <p>Football</p>
          </br>
        </div>
        <div id="swimming">
          <p>Swimming</p>
          </br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flickrphoto">
      <h2>Flickr</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="recenthistory">
      <h2>Recent history</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Jasmine</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[This is a quick image of what it looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c25dk.png)

Thank you for looking at my work and trying to help me understand where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found some issues in your code:

**HTML5:**

1. You should use only one version of jQuery. In this case:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

2. The `<header>` tag goes inside the `<body>` tag.
3. You can use a `class` attribute to associate an action for every `div` instead to use its `id`. For example:

---

```
<div id="nav">
  <div id="tennis" class="request">
    <p>Tennis</p>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="football" class="request">
    <p>Football</p>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="swimming" class="request">
    <p>Swimming</p>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS:**

1. *The images also show up in a column no matter how much I edit them.* Just remove: `flex-direction: column;`.

---

Something like this:

```
.flex-container > div {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

1. Wrap your jQuery code inside of `$(function(){});`. Something like this:

---

```
$(function()
{
   // Code goes here...
});
```

2. The `API_KEY` variable must have a string value inside of double quotes. For example: `let API_KEY = "39417c145483a7fb3ee91c5fe5bc93fe";`.
3. You can use `$(".request").on("click", function() {` to make a request to Flickr API for every category with a single function. I'd suggest to use [`.on("click")`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
4. In your fetchPhoto you have: `data.photos.photo[0].title`. Change to `data.photos.photo[i].title`.
5. Then, in your display function you can print the proper titles by using:

   `<figcaption>${photos[i].title}</figcaption>`

See this example:

[image]

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".request").on("click", function() {
    let searchText = $(this).children().text();
    let API_KEY = "39417c145483a7fb3ee91c5fe5bc93fe";
    let tennisStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&tags=" + searchText + "&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY;
    let photos = [];
    let nrequest;
    let nreceived;

    $.get(tennisStr, function(data) {
      fetchPhoto(data);
    });

    function fetchPhoto(data) {
      nrequest = data.photos.photo.length;
      nreceived = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
        let photoObj = {
          id: data.photos.photo[i].id,
          title: data.photos.photo[i].title
        }
        photos.push(photoObj);
        getSizes(photoObj);
      }

      function getSizes(photoObj) {
        let getSizesStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY + "&photo_id=" + photoObj.id;
        $.get(getSizesStr, function(data) {
          nreceived++;
          photoObj.file = data.sizes.size[5].source;
          photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length - 1].source;
          if (nreceived == nrequest) {
            display(photos);
          }
        });
      }

      function display(photos) {
        let htmlStr = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
          htmlStr += `<figure><a href=${photos[i].file}'><img src = "${photos[i].file}" height = "200" width = "200"></a><figcaption>${photos[i].title}</figcaption></figure>`;
        }
        $("#flickrphoto").html(htmlStr);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

#flickrphoto {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

#recenthistory {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  <title>Sports Album</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Sports Album</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="navigation">
      <h2>Categories</h2><br>
      <div id="nav">
        <div id="tennis" class="request">
          <p>Tennis</p>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div id="football" class="request">
          <p>Football</p>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div id="swimming" class="request">
          <p>Swimming</p>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flickrphoto">
      <h2>Flickr</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="recenthistory">
      <h2>Recent history</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Jasmine</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a good day.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you so much. I was going to make the categories buttons. If I was to do this how do I call upon the button so if someone clicks tennis it only appears with the tennis tag. I'm not sure how to put in multiple apis either, should I just copy and paste the text?

Comment: it hasn't worked and now my page is everywhere and has no columns. I'm confused. How do I make the flickr pictures show like yours did?

Comment: I figure it out but I can't get my flickr images to show now... what should I do? Or why doesnt the text on the left show them on the middle? :(

Comment: nevermind I found out I had to highlight the text. Thank you danny!!

Comment: @JasmineK With this code version, it is not necessary to have multiple API functions. I recommend you use this code. Remember that you now have: `$(".request").on("click", function() {`. Related to the visualization, you must use media queries.

Comment: Hi Danny, I got it working in the end, I have a new problem now. Basically we have to click a photo and a modal thing will pop up with a large version of that photo. I can't seem to get mine to work properly and it has nothing in it and I can't opt back to my other work. I also need to fix this so I can get recent photos from ones you clicked on the right hand side. Any ideas Danny? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866753/image-wont-load-when-clicked-for-larger-image

Comment: where do you happen to put this? I'm not sure on how to implement it, it's driving me nuts

Comment: @JasmineK Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866753/image-wont-load-when-clicked-for-larger-image/49867054#49867054.