# Image wont load when clicked for larger image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

For the assignment I'm doing, you need to get a modal pop out to have larger sizes of the photo appear and you can also click the x to go back. The x wont go back for me and I also can't seem to load the images. Is there anything wrong with my code that I'm missing? I've been staring at my code for ages now. Also we have to make a recently viewed page where the thumbnails are small. Whatever ones you click to enlarge and to appear on the side bar in little thumbnails. Does anyone have any clue how to do this? I can't seem to find any tutorials on it :(

```js
$(function() {
  $(".request").on("click", function() {
    let searchText = $(this).children().text();
    let API_KEY = "MY API KEY";
    let tennisStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&tags=" + searchText + "&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY;
    let photos = [];
    let nrequest;
    let nreceived;

    $.get(tennisStr, function(data) {
      fetchPhoto(data);
    });

    function fetchPhoto(data) {
      nrequest = data.photos.photo.length;
      nreceived = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
        let photoObj = {
          id: data.photos.photo[i].id,
          title: data.photos.photo[i].title
        }
        photos.push(photoObj);
        getSizes(photoObj);
      }

      function getSizes(photoObj) {
        let getSizesStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY + "&photo_id=" + photoObj.id;
        $.get(getSizesStr, function(data) {
          nreceived++;
          photoObj.file = data.sizes.size[3].source;
          photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length - 1].source;
          if (nreceived == nrequest) {
            display(photos);
          }
        });
      }

      function display(photos) {
        let htmlStr = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
          htmlStr += `<figure data-full="${photos[i].full}"><img src = "${photos[i].file}"><figcaption>${photos[i].title}</figcaption></figure>`;
        }
        $("#flickrphoto").html(htmlStr);
        $('figure').each(function (index){
            $(this).click(function(){
                $('#modal-container').css('display', 'block');
                $('modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-full'));
            });
        });
        $("#modal-close").click(function(){
            $('#modal-container').css('display', 'block');
            $('#modal-content').attr('src', '');
        });
      };
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: left;
}

#flickrphoto {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

#recenthistory {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

#modal-container{
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 1;
}
#modal-content{
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
#modal-caption{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#modal-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}


header {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/5/4/9/684187.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/*
THREE COL

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

TWO COL
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

ONE COL
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

*\
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  <title>Sports Album</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Sports Album</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="navigation">
      <h2>Categories</h2><br>
      <div id="nav">
        <div id="tennis" class="request"><button>
          <p>Tennis</p>
          <br /></button>
        </div>
        <div id="football" class="request"><button>
          <p>Football</p>
          <br /></button>
        </div>
        <div id="swimming" class="request"><button>
          <p>Swimming</p</button>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flickrphoto">
      <h2>Welcome to the Sports Album! Click the buttons on the left for sporting photos</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="recenthistory">
      <h3>Recent history</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Jasmine</p>
  </div>
  <div id="modal-container">
     <span id="modal-close">&times;</span>
     <img id="modal-content">
     <div id="modal-caption">Caption</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also is there any reason that flexbox would push the photos over the other two columns?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You are getting `"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"` when making the ajax call. There is no `data.photos` as a result.

Comment: It's most likely because I changed my API key because you can't show it on this website

Comment: A sample response? Like what happens when I tried to click the photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `#` in the jQuery selector function.

Change `$('modal-content')` to `$('#modal-content')`.

---

In order to render the recent viewed images I've updated the `getSizes` function like this:

```
function getSizes(photoObj) {
  let getSizesStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY + "&photo_id=" + photoObj.id;
  $.get(getSizesStr, function(data) {
    nreceived++;
    photoObj.thumbnail = data.sizes.size[2].source; // "label": "Thumbnail",
    photoObj.file = data.sizes.size[3].source; // "label": "Small",
    photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length - 1].source; // "label": "Original",
    if (nreceived == nrequest) {
      display(photos);
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, I've added `photoObj.thumbnail`:

```
photoObj.thumbnail = data.sizes.size[2].source;
```

I declared a global array variable called `viewedImages` to store the recent viewed images.

```
let viewedImages = [];
```

I've added a new function to render the recent viewed images called `showViewedImages()`:

```
function showViewedImages() {
  var len = viewedImages.length, html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    html += "<li><img src=\"";
    html += viewedImages[i];
    html += "\" /></li>";
  }
  $("#viewedImagesList").html(html);
}
```

Throug the `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=39417c145483a7fb3ee91c5fe5bc93fe&photo_id=41465072422` URL method you get all you need.

This is the JSON response:

```
{
  "sizes": {
    "canblog": 0,
    "canprint": 0,
    "candownload": 1,
    "size": [
      {
        "label": "Square",
        "width": 75,
        "height": 75,
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_s.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/sq\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Large Square",
        "width": "150",
        "height": "150",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_q.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/q\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Thumbnail",
        "width": "100",
        "height": "67",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_t.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/t\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Small",
        "width": "240",
        "height": "160",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_m.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/s\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Small 320",
        "width": "320",
        "height": 213,
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_n.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/n\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Medium",
        "width": "500",
        "height": "333",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/m\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Medium 640",
        "width": "640",
        "height": "427",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_z.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/z\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Medium 800",
        "width": "800",
        "height": 534,
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_c.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/c\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Large",
        "width": "1024",
        "height": "683",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_76cb19bf81_b.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/l\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Large 1600",
        "width": "1600",
        "height": 1067,
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_3971a09b92_h.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/h\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Large 2048",
        "width": "2048",
        "height": 1365,
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_f71da7999c_k.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/k\/",
        "media": "photo"
      },
      {
        "label": "Original",
        "width": "3000",
        "height": "2000",
        "source": "https:\/\/farm1.staticflickr.com\/890\/41465072422_08af9d42ac_o.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/54097044@N03\/41465072422\/sizes\/o\/",
        "media": "photo"
      }
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".request").on("click", function() {
    let searchText = $(this).children().text(); // Once you've clicked on a single button with the class "request" you get its children text content. In this case <p> tag has a text content: "Tennis": <button><p>Tennis</p></button>.
    let API_KEY = "39417c145483a7fb3ee91c5fe5bc93fe"; // My API key only test purposes for this question.
    let tennisStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&tags=" + searchText + "&per_page=15&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY;
    let photos = [];
    let nrequest;
    let nreceived;
    let viewedImages = []; // Array variable to store the recent image thumbnail URL.

    $.get(tennisStr, function(data) { // jQuery.get() method wich runs $.ajax() function with GET request type by default.
      fetchPhoto(data); // Inside the anonymous function call the fetchPhoto function with the current data from the API url requested. 
    });

    function fetchPhoto(data) {
      nrequest = data.photos.photo.length; // Gets the length of the "data.photos.photo" array.
      nreceived = 0; // Initialization with 0.
      for (let i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++) {
        let photoObj = { // In this section you're declaration "photoObj" for every iteration.
          id: data.photos.photo[i].id,
          title: data.photos.photo[i].title
        }
        photos.push(photoObj);
        getSizes(photoObj);
      }

      function getSizes(photoObj) {
        let getSizesStr = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=" + API_KEY + "&photo_id=" + photoObj.id;
        $.get(getSizesStr, function(data) {
          nreceived++;
          photoObj.thumbnail = data.sizes.size[2].source; // "label": "Thumbnail",
          photoObj.file = data.sizes.size[3].source; // "label": "Small",
          photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length - 1].source; // "label": "Original",
          if (nreceived == nrequest) {
            display(photos);
          }
        });
      }

      function display(photos) {
        let htmlStr = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
          htmlStr += `<figure data-full="${photos[i].full}" data-thumbnail="${photos[i].thumbnail}"><img src = "${photos[i].file}"><figcaption>${photos[i].title}</figcaption></figure>`;
        }
        $("#flickrphoto").html(htmlStr);
        $('figure').each(function(index) {
          $(this).click(function() {
            viewedImages.push($(this).attr('data-thumbnail')); // We're adding the thumbnail URL value to the viewedImages array.
            $('#modal-container').css('display', 'block');
            $('#modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-full'));
          });
        });
        $("#modal-close").click(function() {
          showViewedImages(); // Call the showViewedImages function to render a list <ul><li><img src="" /></li></ul> with the "photoObj.thumbnail" content.
          $('#modal-container').css('display', 'none');
          $('#modal-content').attr('src', '');
        });
      }

      function showViewedImages() {
        var len = viewedImages.length, html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          html += "<li><img src=\"";
          html += viewedImages[i];
          html += "\" /></li>";
        }
        $("#viewedImagesList").html(html); // Finally, insert the html value to the "viewedImagesList" element. <ul id="viewedImagesList"></ul>
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#navigation {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: left;
}

#flickrphoto {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

#recenthistory {
  flex-grow: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

#modal-container {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
}

#modal-content {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

#modal-caption {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/5/4/9/684187.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.request {
  display: block;
}


/*
THREE COL

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

TWO COL
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

ONE COL
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

*\
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  <title>Sports Album</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Sports Album</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div id="navigation">
      <h2>Categories</h2><br>
      <div id="nav">
        <button class="request"><p>Tennis</p></button>
        <button class="request"><p>Football</p></button>
        <button class="request"><p>Swimming</p></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="flickrphoto">
      <h2>Welcome to the Sports Album! Click the buttons on the left for sporting photos</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="recenthistory">
      <h3>Recent history</h3>
      <ul id="viewedImagesList"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Jasmine</p>
  </div>
  <div id="modal-container">
    <span id="modal-close">&times;</span>
    <img id="modal-content">
    <div id="modal-caption">Caption</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Danny, that worked but now I can't click the x in the corner to go back to the normal images. Do you happen to know also how you would implement a feature where whatever you click has a small thumbnail in the recently viewed column? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to change `$('#modal-container').css('display', 'block');` to `$('#modal-container').css('display', 'none');`. See my update.

Comment: Dan mate I wish I could pay you right now honestly, you are my knight in shining armour. Do you happen to know what to use to make a 'recently viewed' tab on the side though? It's the last thing I need to do besides @media sizes

Comment: Oh actually one more thing, when the image actually appears how do you get the biggest size automatically through the modal?

Comment: Do you mean to be able to see the images recently seen in the "Recent history" section?

Comment: We are using: `photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length - 1].source;` to the get the biggest size in the modal window.

Comment: oh okay, so I don't need to worry about that? And yes I mean when you click it and it enlarges in the modal, it'll appear on the side in a small thumbnail saying that you've recently seen that photo

Comment: See my update. Let me know if you need some details about the new code.

Comment: Hey Danny, I would ask you to help me with media querys but I've run out of time. If possible could you just explain in simple terms what you did?

Comment: Danny mate, love your work. You're a life savior. I have only one request. Could you go through my javascript and just write little comments about what they are/are doing? I do know most of them but I'm worried I'll need to revise and want to make sure it's 100% right

Comment: I have added some comments in the code. See my update.

Comment: In this version we have: `<figure data-full="${photos[i].full}" data-thumbnail="${photos[i].thumbnail}"><img src = "${photos[i].file}"><figcaption>${photos[i].title}</figcaption></figure>`; in the `display()` function.

Comment: danny just letting you know you're a legend and I appreciate everything and all the effort you put in for me. Thank you so much man <3